# Apple Watch to Apple Watch

Tags: ios, bluetooth, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

In the Apple Watch, there is a first-party feature in which one user can send a heartbeat or doodle to another Apple Watch via the Friends list.  Is there an API for this, where users of an app in watchOS can send another user of that app in his or her Friends circle something similar, like a small packet of text or image data?  Would it have to piggyback on the iPhone's Bluetooth, or is there a built-in API or known hack for this?